# How to prevent screen power management from activating?

Tags: x11, awesome-wm, screen-lock

I am using Awesome WM, and I use xscreensaver to lock the screen if I'm away for a certain amount of time. I also enabled screen power management in the xscreensaver configuration to turn off the monitor after some time. I want to implement a "persentation mode", which disables these. I can disable screen locking by calling `xscreensaver-command -deactivate` periodically. However, it doesn't stop the screen from going idle. I tried blocking `idle` in systemd-inhibit, but that doesn't help either.

Is there any way to temporarily disable screen power management in xscreensaver? Or, alternatively, is there any alternative screen locker / power management tool that allows locking the screen, turning off the screen, and temporarily disabling itself from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what exactly turns off your screen. You can give `xset` a try. You can control the screensaver (screen going black after some while) with it. For example `xset s off`.

From `man xset`:

```
For screen-saver control:
 s [timeout [cycle]]  s default    s on
 s blank              s noblank    s off
 s expose             s noexpose
 s activate           s reset
```

For screen locking I love to use `slock`.

EDIT: Slock doen't have a auto lock capability. You need a tool (for example `xautolock`) which watches your X and calls slock.

```
xautolock -time 2 -locker slock
```

Comment: How do you schedule slock to be run after certain amount of inactivity?

Comment: Slock doen't have that capability. You need a tool (for example `xautolock`) which watches your X and calls slock.
```xautolock -time 2 -locker slock```

Comment: This one requires some workarounds too, but it works.